# Why can't set state directly inside of MUI DataGrid renderCell?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to render a DataGrid (MUI) and have one of the columns contain a link to another react router page.

The following code does not display the MACID (`params.value.macid`) properly:

```
const columns = [
{ field: 'macid', headerName: 'MACID', width: 250,
    renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams<String>) => (
      <strong>
        {params.value.macid}
        <a href="#" onClick={() => HandleDeviceClick(params.value.macid)}>GO</a>
      </strong>
    ) },
```

[image]

However, if I use this code it will display the MACID:

```
const columns = [
{ field: 'macid', headerName: 'MACID', width: 250,
    renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams<String>) => (
      params.value.macid
    ) },
```

[image]

More code that builds the rows...

```
for (var x in props.statsData) {
    if (props.statsData[x].cpu_us === null) {
        cpu = 0;
    } else {
        cpu = parseInt(props.statsData[x].cpu_us);
    }
    if (props.statsData[x].ramused === null) {
        ram = 0;
    } else {
        ram = parseInt(props.statsData[x].ramused);
    }
    if (props.statsData[x].disk1used === null) {
        disk = 0;
    } else {
        disk = parseInt(props.statsData[x].disk1used);
    }
    if (props.statsData[x].temperature === null) {
        temp = 0;
    } else {
        temp = parseInt(props.statsData[x].temprature);
    }
  rows.push(createData(counter, props.statsData[x].deviceID, cpu, ram, disk, temp))
  counter += 1;
}

function createData(id, macid, cpu, ram, disk, temperature) {
  return {
    id,
    macid,
    cpu,
    ram,
    disk,
    temperature,
  };
}
```

```html
<div style={{ height: 800, width: '100%' }}>
  <DataGrid
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    pageSize={25}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[25]}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: to use link, buttons or any other actions, please use `type: actions` and `getActions` function. https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#special-properties

Comment: @PrashantJangam It is automatically executing the code inside the onClick (in getActions) on page render, do you know why?

Comment: try using arrow function inside onclick `onClick={()=>yourFunction}`

Answer (score 0):

**You can't use hooks directly inside of a renderCell function**

if you want to use hooks inside of a renderCell function you should use it as component

for your example it is look like this

```
const Alink = (props) => {
  const [handleDeviceClick, setHandleDeviceClick] = useState(0);

  return (
    <a href="#" onClick={() => setHandleDeviceClick(props.macid)}>GO</a>
  );
};

const column = {
  // ...other properties,
  renderCell: () => ( 
      <strong>
        {params.value.macid}
        <Alink macid={params.value.macid}/>
      </strong>)
,
};
```

also you can read this :
[Using hooks inside a renderer](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#using-hooks-inside-a-renderer)